# Adding Next and Prev button to my slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a next and previous button to my image slider, but I don't know how to do.
Plz help. I have a basic structure..?

Here is my code..

**HTML**

```
     <div class="large-photo">
         <img src="images/large-photo/photo1.jpg" class="active">
         <img src="images/large-photo/photo2.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="small-photo">
         <img src="images/small-photo/photo1.jpg" class="thumb selected">
         <img src="images/small-photo/photo2.jpg" class="thumb">
     </div>
     <div class="arrow">
         <div class="left-arrow"></div>
         <div class="right-arrow"></div>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.large-photo img {
     display: none;
 }
 .large-photo img.active  {
     display:block;
 }
 .small-photo img.selected {
     border: 3px solid red;
 }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
   function loadPhoto() {
        $('.small-photo img').click(function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('.large-photo img.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.large-photo img').eq(index).addClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

Comment: > [Very Simple Image Slider/Slideshow with left and right button. No autoplay][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761868/very-simple-image-slider-slideshow-with-left-and-right-button-no-autoplay

check this.

Comment: hi @jurina sorry for late reply i was busy in some work and now i got some thime to answer you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was some difficult for me to understand what you want as preer according to your code but however you will under stand how this sytem works and also how to use it differently. CODE:

```
<style type="text/css">

    #container{
        width: 266px ;
        height:128px ;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#left-arrow").click(function(){

            $(".small-photo").fadeIn();
            $(".large-photo").fadeOut();
        });

        $("#right-arrow").click(function(){
            $(".small-photo").fadeOut();
            $(".large-photo").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });


</script> 

<div id="container">
<div class="large-photo">
         <img src="images/1395924816_personal-information.png">
         <img src="images/1395938204_lock.png">
     </div>
     <div class="small-photo">
         <img src="images/1395939936_application-pgp-signature.png" >
         <img src="images/1396010974_button-cross_basic_red.png" >
     </div>

    </div>
     <div class="arrow">
          <a href="#" id="left-arrow">&lt;-</a> 
          <a href="#" id="right-arrow">-></a> 
      </div>
```

and yes i had to do some of the major chages such as removing CSS but you can add but for my convinence i removed it just to show you how to do what you want i also change some of the class to id.. etc and also change pictures and you replace all thos pictures to your pictures..

working [`demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/F3Bg9/)

Comment: also you can change the size of container according to the size of your picture

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I want to slide without fade effect. My woking demo is http://jsfiddle.net/uq3Pr/1/
How can i add next and prev button to it ?